# Conditional count group by in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a code to count records in 7 days:

```
  var r=  (from t in _context.Services
         where
            t.ServiceDate.Date >= FirstDay.Date &&
            t.ServiceDate.Date <= SeventhDay.Date 
         group t by new { t.ServiceDate.Year, t.ServiceDate.Month, t.ServiceDate.Day, t.Solution } into g
         select new DateAndCoint 
         { 
             date = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, g.Key.Day),
             count = g.Count() })
         .ToList();
```

It's work fine, but as I have field called **Solution** (bool) which indicate whether record done or not

so I like to count done records (which Solution is true) **beside** the above count?
I tried :

```
countDone = g.Where(x=>x.Solution).Count()
```

### but it give me a runtime error

```
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: new {
Year = (DATEPART((year), (s.ServiceDate))),
Month = (DATEPART((month), (s.ServiceDate))),
Day = (DATEPART((day), (s.ServiceDate))),
Solution = (s.Solution)
},
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression:
EntityType: Service
ValueBufferExpression:
(ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
IsNullable: False
)
)
.Where(x => x.Solution)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

---

is there any idea ho to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such `Count` supported in EF Core 5.x. Since your query does not work, you can emulate `Count` as `Sum`

```cs
 var query = 
    from t in _context.Services
    where
        t.ServiceDate.Date >= FirstDay.Date &&
        t.ServiceDate.Date <= SeventhDay.Date 
    group t by new { t.ServiceDate.Year, t.ServiceDate.Month, t.ServiceDate.Day, t.Solution } into g
    select new DateAndCoint 
    { 
        date = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, g.Key.Day),
        count = g.Count(),
        countDone = g.Sum(x => x.Solution ? 1 : 0) 
    };
```